# For what use cases are AppSync pipeline resolvers better then express step functions?

Tags: aws-appsync, aws-step-functions, aws-appsync-resolver

I am currently creating a AppSync API and after figuring out that I can use step functions as a resolver I was wondering why I would ever use a pipeline resolver?

Pipeline resolvers are significantly more complex and unwieldy to construct and maintain and are a pain to debug, whereas with step functions I get a graphical representation of my architecture and a very easy debugging interface.

But when I look at the fact that step functions is not a native resolver integration and the sparse documentation on this topic I am wondering what the disadvantages to this solution are, and in what cases the pipeline resolver is superior and why?

Answer (score 0):

Step functions and pipeline resolvers have two completely different use cases. Step functions are for control flow where the decision of one "step" decides the direction it takes to execute the next step. Pipeline functions are for a sequential execution of functions.

If the end target of the resolver code was step functions you could still use a pipeline resolver to first authorizer the request before the final function that used step functions, or any other target.